# Python beautifulsoup looking at class with space at the end

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find a class tag of `'product '` (including the space at the end), it doesn't return anything using this code:
xxx - I cannot discuss what i am doing with detail (NDA)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = 'xxx'
source = requests.get(page).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for tile in soup.find_all('div', class_='product'):
    print(tile)
```

There are multiple instances of this class repeated for each product on the site and i want to loop to them individually.

Comment: Then, you need to pass `product ` (with space at the end) to the `class` argument like so:`soup.find_all('div', class_='product ')`

Answer (score 0):

try to turn

```py
for tile in soup.find_all('div', class_='product'):
    print(tile)
```

into this

```py
for tile in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'product '}):
    print(tile)
```